# Running Django with MySql

Tags: mysql, django, database-connection

I have an existing MySQL database for users, and I have a separate django website that currently uses sqlite for all database storage such as users, inventory and news.

Is it possible to connect both of those? The connection that I want is for the project to use the existing users tables and two new tables for inventory and news.

I was looking a lot through the documentation of mysql in django, but there where links to other links to more links, and none of them provided with enough information for me to do this process.

Also would anyone know how to view the tables that are created in sqlite? I will need them to create tables in MySql.

Maybe someone here had the same issue and could share the experience? I would really appreciate advice on steps to take

the system that will be running this project is debian if that helps. Any comments view or opinions are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply looking to use multiple databases, django 1.2 offers the feature.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/